# Converting string text to same binary data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to read some values from an XML file, say the values represent the reset state of a hardware register. The `<Field_Reset_Value>10</Field_Reset_Value>` represent two bits here as "1" and "0" respectively. I need to use these values to shift and bitwise or with other bit values further.

Now when I read the value, it is represented as a string. Can someone suggest the way, I can convert string to binary. Say as the example below.

```
string = "10"
```

Now I want to convert its binary value as `binval = 0b10`.

Also, these values can be of any number of bits from 1 to 32 bit. What I mean is the string can also be `1101001110011` so I will need to represent it as `0b1101001110011`

Comment: `int('10', 2)` will give you the integer `2`. `bin(int('10', 2))`  will give you the string `"0b10"`. Likewise `int('1101001110011', 2)` gives the integer `6771`

Comment: Hey thanks Mark. I missed converting it to integer with base 2, so I was getting different results. This helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```py
>>> st = "hello world"
>>> ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in st)
'1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1110111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100'

#using `bytearray`
>>> ' '.join(format(x, 'b') for x in bytearray(st, 'utf-8'))
'1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1110111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100'
```